# Simple query with CActiveDataProvider - Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

How can i build this query in "CActiveDataProvider":

```
$var = word;

    SELECT table_a.name, table_b.name
    FROM table_a
    LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.bid
    WHERE table_a.name LIKE '%$var%'
```

i have this model so far:

```
class Table_a extends CActiveRecord {

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName() {
        return Yii::app()->db->tablePrefix.'table_a';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CDbCrtieria object for this 
refer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria

In your case it will be like this in your controller

```
<?php 
// .... Wherever you need the dataProvider, usually the action in the controller

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addSeachCondition('table_a.name',$var,true,"AND","LIKE");
$criteria->join = "LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b ON t.id = table_b.bid";
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('table_a',array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code, but it should must work:

```
$dataProv=new CActiveDataProvider('Table_a',array(
          'criteria'=>array(
              'select'=>"table_a.name, table_b.name",
              'condition'=>"table_a.name LIKE '%$var%'",
              'join'=>"LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.bid",
          )));
```